# how to render xml svg response in blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

"I call an api that return a qrcode in xml svg format. I want to display that qrcode in blade view. I am stack with displaying the xml svg response in blade view."

I get an xml svg qrcode in controller from an API that I call, I want to display it in blade

In controller, this is how I render data to blade

```php
return response()
    ->view(
        'qrcode',
        [
            'output' => $output
        ],
        200
    )
    ->header('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');
```

This is how my blade look like:

```xml
<svg {{$output}}></svg>
```

I expect to see variable an svg xml qrcode (`$output` variable contain it)on blade view

Comment: What is the content of `$output`?

Comment: The content look this:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 59 59" stroke="none">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
    <path d="M1,1h1v1h-1z M2,1h1v1h-1z M3,1h1v1h-1z M4,1h1v1h-1z M5,1h1v1h-1z M6,1h1v1h-1z M7,1h1v1h-1z M9,1h1v1h-1-----" fill="#000000"/>
</svg>

Answer (score 2):

Try this it works for me:

```
<?php 

   $file_path = file_get_contents(public_path('client/assets/images') .'/'. $filename);
   
   return response($file_path)->header('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');
  /*The public path above is path to *.svg file*/

?>
```

Further we can use it on an image tag like this:

```
<img src="/assets/images/logo.svg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the output between the svg tags

```
<svg>{{ $output }}</svg>
```

Comment: I receive this error when doing that: "This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 6: error parsing attribute name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Response` and attach the header to that, not the View.

```
$response = Response::make(View::make('qrcode', ['output' => $output]), 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');
return $response;
```

I'd also suggest just adding the header in your view, also:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml'); ?>

{{ $output }} <!-- Try without SVG tags seems as you have XML tags in your $output anyway -->
```

For more info, refer to [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses)